# Places where an expression can occur as per the JLS?

Tags: java, expression, jls

Consider the Article **§15.1** regarding places where the expression can occur:

> An expression occurs in either:
>
> • The declaration of some (class or interface) type that is being declared: in a
> field initializer, in a static initializer, in an instance initializer, in a constructor
> declaration, in a method declaration, or in an annotation.
>
> • An annotation on a package declaration or on a top level type declaration.

I don't think this is exhaustive list of all occurrence places for expression - as eg:

```java
int a=23; //declaration of a local type
a=33; //this is re-initialization of the type

//or like a simple method invocation from inside a method like
foo();
```

- The places where we are trying to re-initialize the expression are not highlighted by this clause.
- also the simple method invocation is not being highlighted in the above clause - even though it is a formal expression.

**Is the clause above correct - or is just a casual statement in the JLS?**

Comment: There are no "casual statements" in the JLS. The list is complete. Note that you are not allowed to write the line `a=33;` at some random place in the class declaration - it must be in one of those places mentioned in the first bullet point (for example in a method declaration or in a constructor).

Comment: @ThomasKläger - but I think that the JLS must also have commented on the placement of the above expression in the method body as well. There is not mention of  the method body in the list.

Comment: The method body is part of the method declaration ([8.4. Method Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4)) and is therefore implicitly included. It is not necessary to add it separately to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That clause is actually true, though it is not stated in a precise way.

For example:

- `a=33;`

  The `a=33` is an expression, and when followed by a `;` it is also an expression statement.  An expression statement is only allowed where other statements are allowed; i.e. *within* a method or constructor declaration (in the *body*), or in an instance or `static` initializer (block).

  Note that in the JLS, a method's body is *part of* the method's declaration.  That is why we can say that statements are *within* a method declaration.
- `foo();`

  The `foo()` call is an expression, and when followed by a `;` it is also an expression statement; see above.

It is a matter of understanding what is meant by "in" in this context.  It means "inside of" rather than "directly inside of".

The imprecision arises when you consider that an expression statement that is inside of a method declaration that is inside of a class is ... also *indirectly* inside the class.

You could argue that the clause descriptive rather than normative since they don't specify precisely what "in" means in this context.  But even so, the description is correct if you interpret it as above.

---

Your `int a=23;` "example" is not an expression, so it is not apropos to the point you are trying to make.  It could be a statement, or it could be a (package private) field declaration that is "in" a class or interface declaration.